# Timestamp when Condition is Met

Tags: google-sheets

I currently have a master doc that is shared with 4 other individuals. Right now, I have a formula that time stamps column L with today's date when column K has either "Closed" or "Same Day Close." What we are finding is that sometimes the time stamps are inaccurate and will reflect today's date on closes that happened last week, for example. I believe this is occurring because there are so many people accessing the do, correct? Here is the formula I'm currently using:

```
=IF(OR(K34="Closed",K34="Same Day Close"),TODAY(),"")
```

So I'm thinking it would be best to do a script instead so the time stamps are not affected by the multiple users accessing the doc at different times. It's working, but it's not doing exactly what I need it to do. Here's the script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var activatedSheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var activatedCell = ss.getActiveSelection();
  var activatedCellRow = activatedCell.getRow();
  var activatedCellColumn = activatedCell.getColumn();
  var activatedCellValue = activatedCell.getValue();

  var greg = ss.getSheetByName("Greg"); // source sheet
  var greg = ss.getSheetByName("Greg"); // target sheet

  // if the value in column D is "Approved", move the row to target sheet
  if (activatedSheetName == greg.getName() && activatedCellColumn == 11 && activatedCellValue == "Closed") {
  // add date and time of when approved to target row in column E
    greg.getRange('l' + activatedCellRow).setValue(Date(TODAY));
  }
}
```

Here's what it's not doing that I need it to do:

1. I don't want the timestamp to include anything other than today's
   date in mm/dd/yyyy format (right now it includes time as well)
2. I need "Closed" as well as "Same Day Close" to trigger the timestamp
3. I need the code to apply to multiple sheets, not just to "Greg"

Thank you so much in advance! This is my first time trying to implement a script and I've been playing with it for days to no avail. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.columnStart !== 11 || e.value !== 'Close' && e.value !== 'Same Day Close') return;
e.range.offset(0, 1)
    .setValue(new Date())
}
```

Note: to get rid of the time, simply format the column L as 'DATE' (via the 123-button in the menu).